# Graphical problem Mint Cinamon Interface

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, graphics, ati

I am using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinamon. Everything is on the picture but I try to explain. When I run some linux applications windows are fully transparent. I can see only borders of those windows. There is also strange problem with icons near clock in the bottom-right corner.

For example the terminal is fully transparent and I can't use it but I know that it works because when I use the terminal from RubyMine it works. The same thing is when I start virtual terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

External applications installed works fine but some apps strictly from Linux Mint got this problem. http://prntscr.com/8gqf8z